# Is it possible to have variables that don't end up with its own memory?

Tags: c++, c

When learning C and C++, I was told:

1. that every variable has its own block of memory
2. and the address of that chunk of memory never changes during the lifetime of the variable.

So I wonder those two statements are actually true? Is it possible to have variables that don't end up with their own memory?

For example

```c
int a = 1
int b = a
```

in the above example, it is possible that any of the variables don't get their dedicated block of memory allocated? For example, when the variables are loaded directly into registers without **being first stored in the memory**?

Comment: Depending on what the compiler decides to do, a variable can be stored on a general purpose register. Thus it won't be an *lvalue*.

Comment: hi can I ask what is `lvalue`?

Comment: Depending on what you do with `a` and `b`, I have seen compiler optimizers totally eliminate both variables, and be able to figure out the final result, and store that result in a register.

Comment: @digito_evo Value categories never depend on compiler optimizations.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie "store that result in a register" in which case either the result or `a` or `b` needs to be stored in the memory first right?

Comment: @Joji -- No.  The compiler computes the "answer" internally.  I had answered a question some time ago, where the question was about moving the digits around in an integer.  I wrote up an answer that did divisions, if statements, etc.  I was shocked that the compiler did all of that work, and just had one line of assembly code -- the final answer, stored in a register.

Comment: is there an official term for such behavior - "The compiler computes the "answer" internally."? Or it is just generally being referred to as "optimization"?

Comment: On the programmer's side, it is "compile-time computation".  On the compiler side, it is "aggressive optimization".

Comment: That fall under the general topic “Compile time evaluation and optimization”

Comment: Have a look at [Value Categories](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category). Essentially an *lvalue* is an expression that can be on both sides of the assignment operator `=`. It has an identity and can not be moved from.

Comment: C 2018 6.7 5 says that a *definition* of an object “causes storage to be reserved for that object”.

Answer (score 6):

The C++ standard allows the C++ compiler to perform any optimization that has no observable effects.

If your C++ compiler can prove to itself that, for your example, using `b` as a mere alias for `a` will have no observable effects, then it is permitted, but not obligated, to compile this optimization which will have the effect of `b` not existing at all and not using any memory; and all references to `b` actually using `a`.

But you have absolutely no way to know that, except via external means such as using an external debugger, perhaps. If you had a way to know that, in the context of the C++ program, then, of course, making this optimization would have an observable effect and your C++ compiler will not do that.

Comment: Hi it is correct to say that "the address of that chunk of memory never changes during the lifetime of the variable."?

Comment: Depends on what "correct" means. It is true that all modern operating systems work this way: a particular symbol has a fixed address that does not change. But, again, there's nothing in the C++ standard that refers to a "memory address". The C++ standard specifies the observed results of a well-formed C++ program. If a compiler or an operating system can effect the change, but without any observed results, than that's that. And, in fact, modern operating systems do that all the time. With virtual memory, a given object may actually may get moved around in physical memory.

Comment: A quick question about virtual memory: when we are drawing diagrams about memory address using hexadecimal. like diagram in this book https://openframeworks.cc/ofBook/chapters/memory.html, are they normally virtual memory address or physical memory address? Also "a given object may actually may get moved around in physical memory.", is there a term for this behavior conducted by OS or can I have a link to learn more about this?

Answer (score 0):

@SamVarshavchik is focusing on implementation.

But from the language point of view, only the `register` variables are guaranteed to do not have the reference (even if the implementation will place it in the memory). All other objects **have** references to them - thus they have representation in the memory.

The implementation might choose what to do with those objects (optimize them out, place them in the register, etc etc).

But if you use the reference to the object it will representation in the memory.

> that every variable has its own block of memory
> and the address of that chunk of memory never changes during the lifetime of the variable.

It is the observable behaviour if the reference is used.

https://godbolt.org/z/K36zxKozE

Comment: 1. "But if you use the reference to the object it will representation in the memory." not sure I understand this - could you clarify what "reference" means here? Or give me an example?
2. In https://godbolt.org/z/K36zxKozE, what purpose does allocateMatrix serve here - sorry for my newbie question
3. it is correct to say that "and the address of that chunk of memory never changes during the lifetime of the variable."